# Java Eclipse Error "cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java

Im trying to model a solar system but am running into an issue.

```
public class Main 
{

public static void main(String[] args) {

       drawSolarObject sun = new drawSolarObject(5,5,20,"YELLOW");
          s.finishedDrawing();


 public class Solar
{
  public void drawSolarObject(double distance, double angle, double diameter, String col)
```

This is giving me an error

> "drawSolarObject cannot be resolved to a type"

and im not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this is not an Eclipse problem. This means that the type drawSolarObject isn't on your classpath. you are mixing up classes and methods

Comment: Im sorry im not sure what you mean. Do you know how I could go about fixing this?

Comment: you'll have to learn the basics. I've pointed out the biggest issues of the code you've shown in my answer

Comment: You should leanr more Java before trying to use Java to solve problem you don"t understand

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is a bit vague and won't compile (methods declared inside methods?)

You need something like:

```
public class Main 
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
       Solar solar = new Solar();
       solar.drawSolarObject(5,5,20,"YELLOW"); 
       //   s.finishedDrawing(); --> no idea about this
} // missing end of method
} // missing end of class


 public class Solar
{
  public void drawSolarObject(double distance, double angle, double diameter, String col)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would work:

```
public Class Main{
Solar sun = new Solar();
sun.drawSolarObject(5,5,20,"YELLOW");
}
public class Solar{
 public void drawSolarObject(double distance, double angle, double diameter, String col)
}
```

You tried to make an instance of a method instead of a class.
You can't do the following:

'MethodName' name = new 'MethodName';

Comment: Was writing at the same time, didn't see it before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate drawSolarObject as it is not a class but a instance function of the class Solar. You'd need something like this to call the drawSolarObject method:

```
Solar sun = new Solar();
sun.drawSolarObject(5,5,20,"YELLOW");
```

Then you are instantiating "sun", an instance of the Solar class; this instance can be used to call the method drawSolarObject it contains.

You can also make the method drawSolarObject static and call it like this:

```
Solar.drawSolarObject(5,5,20,"YELLOW");
```

In this case you don't need to instantiate a Solar object as the drawSolarObject method is static.

Comment: Taking in account than the OP is totally lost just by creating an instance an invoking a method, don't complicate the situation talking about static stuff...